# Import binary PLY files and using Point Cloud Library for segmentation

Tags: image-segmentation, point-cloud-library, ply-file-format

I have generated binary point clouds (PLY) using Visual Structure from Motion which I have viewed in Meshlab.  The point clouds are points only with no faces.  I would like to load these files into PCL and do segmentation, but I have having issues getting the files to be read properly.  The code (using loadPLYFile) runs, but is unable to generate indices.

```
  pcl::search::Search <pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr tree = boost::shared_ptr<pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);

  pcl::PointCloud <pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud <pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
  if ( pcl::io::loadPLYFile <pcl::PointXYZRGB> ("file.ply", *cloud) == -1 )
    {
      std::cout << "Cloud reading failed." << std::endl;
      return (-1);
    }

  pcl::IndicesPtr indices (new std::vector <int>);
  pcl::PassThrough<pcl::PointXYZRGB> pass;
  pass.setInputCloud (cloud);
  pass.setFilterFieldName ("z");
  pass.setFilterLimits (0.0, 5.0);
  pass.filter (*indices);

  pcl::RegionGrowingRGB<pcl::PointXYZRGB> reg;
  reg.setInputCloud (cloud);
  reg.setIndices (indices);
  reg.setSearchMethod (tree);
  reg.setDistanceThreshold (10);
  reg.setPointColorThreshold (6);
  reg.setRegionColorThreshold (5);
  reg.setMinClusterSize (300);
```

This code gives the following errors when run:

> [pcl::RegionGrowingRGB::prepareForSegmentation] Empty given indices!
>   [pcl::KdTreeFLANN::setInputCloud] Cannot create a KDTree with an empty
>   input cloud!

Comment: Did you try using `pcl_ply2pcd` to convert PLY to PCD and then using that for further processing?